# Manipulating Equations

Tags: equation-solving

I would like to be able to manipulate algebraic equations.  For example, let's say I enter

`3x+5==2`

I would next like to be able to manually subtract $2$ from both sides.  I tried the obvious thing `%-2`, but this just returns

`-2+(3x+5==2)`

Is there a way to

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How do you like this:

```
a = 3 x + 5 == 2;
Subtract[#, 2] & /@ a
```

(* 3 + 3 x == 0 *)

Edit:
(according to rcollyer's advice)

```
Subtract[#, 2] & /@(3 x + 5 == 2)
```

Edit:
(according to J.M's advice)

```
(#-2)&/@(3 x + 5 == 2)
```

Comment: +1, clever. It can be made a one-liner, though, by replacing `a` in the second line with `(3 x + 5 == 2)` where the parentheses are vital.

Comment: @ rcollyer, I've updated it.

Comment: You could have shortened further to `# - 2 & /@ (3 x + 5 == 2)`.

Comment: @J.M., it is a great idea. See for my update.

Comment: Last 2 cents. Some may be tempted to try and use the first level `Apply` (`@@@`) instead of `Map` here, but it won't work because `2` on the RHS is atomic, i.e. it has no `Head` to replace.

Comment: Why does `(#-2)&/@(3x+5==2)` work, but not `((3x+5==2)-2)`.  My understanding is that `(#-2)&` defines a function that takes one unnamed argument and `/@(3x+5==2)` sends the argument `(3x+5==2)` into the function, which, I would have thought, would be equivalent to `((3x+5==2)-2)`, but evidently it is not.  Why?

Answer (score 7):

This works nicely:

```
3 x + 5 == 2
5 + 3 x == 2

Thread[% - 2, Equal]
3 + 3 x == 0
```

Roman Maeder's old [`EqualThread` package](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/4491/) may be of interest, but I haven't tested for compatibility with new versions.

Answer (score 3):

Let me note in addition that one may want to look at the TreeForm of the equation:

```
> eq = 3*x + 5 == 2

> TreeForm[eq, ImageSize -> 150]
```

and get the following

[image]

Now one may address any element of equation separately, exactly as it is done on the paper. Say,

```
> eq[[1, 2]]
```

> 3 x

This, in fact, stays behind the approaches proposed above. In the simple case discussed in this post it is, of course, too much, but will fast become necessary, as soon as one goes to a bit more complex equations.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple attempt at a function which will do the manipulation for any function with the `NumericFunction` attribute.

```
threq[func_[x___,HoldPattern@Equal[y__]]/;MemberQ[Attributes@func,NumericFunction]]:=
Equal@@(func[x,#]&/@{y});
threq[x___] := x
```

Examples:

```
In[3]:= threq[(3x+5==2)-2]
Out[3]= 3+3 x==0

In[4]:= threq[(3x+5==2)a]
Out[4]= a (5+3 x)==2 a

In[5]:= threq[Sin[3x+5==2]]
Out[5]= Sin[5+3 x]==Sin[2]

In[6]:= threq[f[3x+5==2]]
Out[6]= f[5+3 x==2]
```