# Getting the polynomial from a polinomial root equation

Tags: polynomials

After doing some preceding work I end up with a polynomial equation that should look something like this:

```
Eq = c + b x + a x^2 - d x^2 == k
```

I would like to convert this equation to

```
Eq = c + b x + a x^2 - d x^2 - k == 0
```

then extract the LHS into a variable:

```
Poly = c + b x + a x^2 - d x^2 - k
```

and proceed with my analysis to do things like

```
Collect[Poly,x]
```

which would return

```
c - k + b x + (a - d) x^2
```

Is there a way to automate this procedure?

Comment: [Related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7139/862)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
eq = c + b x + a x^2 - d x^2 == k;

Collect[Subtract @@ eq, x]
```

or

```
Collect[eq /. Equal -> Subtract, x]
```

both give

```
(* c - k + b x + (a - d) x^2 *)
```

Comment: `Subtract @@ eq` works perfectly! Can you explain how this works? I understand that `@@` applies `eq` as argument to `Subtract`, but nowhere in the documentation of subtract does it mention how it treats the `==`

Comment: @Miguel, see [`Apply (@@)`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html) : `Apply[f,expr]` or `f@@expr` replaces the _head_ of `expr` by `f`.  The head of `eq` is `Equal` (you can see that by checking `FullForm[eq]` and/or `Head[eq]`)  and `Apply[Subtract, eq]` (or `Subtract@@ eq`) replaces `Equal` with `Subtract` so that `Equal[something]` becomes `Subtract[something]`. Btw thank you for the accept.

Answer (score 2):

one way

```
Clear[c, b, x, a, d, k, lhs, rhs];
eq = c + b x + a x^2 - d x^2 == k;
lhs = eq /. (lhs_) == (rhs_) -> lhs;
rhs = eq /. (lhs_) == (rhs_) -> rhs;
poly = lhs - rhs == 0;
Collect[poly, x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]